# VBA - Change date in excel from datetime to mm/dd/yy (change to string datatype, not just the cosmetic format)

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm trying to populate a date from a data source in which the date is formatted as `datetime`. The destination file can only accept the `mm/dd/yy` format to upload to our system, but everything that I try is either only cosmetically formatting the date (*i.e. `datetime` still shows in the formula bar*) or converts the data to `m/d/yyyy` which also won't work.

Below is what I've tried, with no success:

Via VBA (only cosmetically changes the format):

```
[T:T].Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Using VBA to create a temporary helper column U with the below formula (gets me to m/d/yyyy:

`=MONTH(T2)&"/"&DAY(T2)&"/"&YEAR(T2)`

I know that I can create a bunch of conditional statements to make the above work, but was curious if there was a less convoluted way to solve what seems like a very simple problem.

Edit: To be clear, the result will likely have to be stored as a string.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "only cosmetically changes the format"? Excel and VBA both store dates as numbers (VT_DATE) and the format is *always* just cosmetic. Do you need it to be a string instead?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - you are correct. I do need it to be a string instead.

Comment: You will need to loop the range and use `Range("T" & i) = Format(Range("T" & i),"mm/dd/yy")` where i is the loop variable.

Comment: *"excel will always store dates as m/d/yyyy"* that's wrong. Excel *always* stores dates as integer numbers. Actually the number that is stored is the amount of days since `1900-01-01` (which is stored as `1`). So everything you see like `m/d/yyyy` is just cosmetics, the value that is stored is a number of days.

Comment: With my advice you will also need to format the cells as text: `Range("T" & i).NumberFormat = "@"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Scott Craner's advice, the following loop worked perfectly!

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Range("T" & i).NumberFormat = "@" 'Format as text to prevent excel from taking over
    Range("T" & i) = Format(Range("T" & i), "mm/dd/yy")
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vDB
    Dim i As Long, r As Long

    Set rngDB = Range("t1", Range("t" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    vDB = rngDB
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 1 To r
        vDB(i, 1) = Format(vDB(i, 1), "mm/dd/yy")
        vDB(i, 1) = Replace(vDB(i, 1), "-", "/")
    Next i
    rngDB.NumberFormatLocal = "@"
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the NumberFormat to text.  Here is an example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetDateTime()
  Dim lngRow As Long
  For lngRow = 1 To 10
    Cells(lngRow, 20).Value = Now
  Next lngRow
End Sub

Sub ReformatDate()
  Dim lngRow As Long
  Dim datX As Date
  Dim strX As String

  For lngRow = 1 To 10
    strX = Cells(lngRow, 20).Value
    If IsDate(strX) Then
      datX = CDate(strX)
      Cells(lngRow, 20).NumberFormat = "@"
      Cells(lngRow, 20).Value = Format(datX, "mm/dd/yy")
    End If
  Next lngRow
End Sub
```